# Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: java, spring, dependencias

soy nueva con Spring y necesito ayuda. Tengo entre otras, estas clases:

```
package com.cice.crud.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name="datosPago")
public class DatosPago implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="idDatosPago")
private Long idDatosPago;

@Column(name="saldo")
private float saldo;

//Relaciones uno a muchos
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idDatosPago")
@IndexColumn(name="idx")    
private List<CuentaBancaria> cuentasBancarias;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idDatosPago")
@IndexColumn(name="idx")    
private List<Tarjeta> tarjetas;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idDatosPago")
@IndexColumn(name="idx")
private List<Paypal> paypal;

public Long getIdDatosPago() {
    return idDatosPago;
}

public void setIdDatosPago(Long idDatosPago) {
    this.idDatosPago = idDatosPago;
}

public float getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}

public void setSaldo(float saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
}

public List<CuentaBancaria> getCuentasBancarias() {
    return cuentasBancarias;
}

public void setCuentasBancarias(List<CuentaBancaria> cuentasBancarias) {
    this.cuentasBancarias = cuentasBancarias;
}

public List<Tarjeta> getTarjetas() {
    return tarjetas;
}

public void setTarjetas(List<Tarjeta> tarjetas) {
    this.tarjetas = tarjetas;
}

public List<Paypal> getPaypal() {
    return paypal;
}

public void setPaypal(List<Paypal> paypal) {
    this.paypal = paypal;
}

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
    }



}
```

Y esta otra (las clases paypal y cuentaBancaria son iguales)

```
package com.cice.crud.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tarjeta")
public class Tarjeta implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="idTarjeta")
private Long idTarjeta;

@Column(name="numeroTarjeta")
private String numeroTarjeta;

//Relacion muchos a uno
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idDatosPago")
private DatosPago datosPago;

public Long getIdTarjeta() {
    return idTarjeta;
}

public void setIdTarjeta(Long idTarjeta) {
    this.idTarjeta = idTarjeta;
}

public String getNumeroTarjeta() {
    return numeroTarjeta;
}

public void setNumeroTarjeta(String numeroTarjeta) {
    this.numeroTarjeta = numeroTarjeta;
}

public DatosPago getDatosPago() {
    return datosPago;
}

public void setDatosPago(DatosPago datosPago) {
    this.datosPago = datosPago;
}

}
```

Este es mi application.context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Use xsd instead of DTD -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
   default-autowire="byName"> <!-- Set default autowiring to byName so that beans are injected based on Name not by TYPE -->

<!-- Definitions of beans used for dependency injection -->
<bean id="user" class="com.reeves.crud.domain.User" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="userService" class="com.reeves.crud.service.UserServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="userRepository" class="com.reeves.crud.service.UserRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="cuentaBancaria" class="com.cice.crud.domain.CuentaBancaria" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="cuentaBancariaService" class="com.cice.crud.service.CuentaBancariaServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="cuentaBancariaRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.CuentaBancariaRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="paypal" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Paypal" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="paypalService" class="com.cice.crud.service.PaypalServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="paypalRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.PaypalRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="tarjeta" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Paypal" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="tarjetaService" class="com.cice.crud.service.PaypalServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="tarjetaRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.PaypalRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="datosPago" class="com.cice.crud.domain.DatosPago" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="datosPagoService" class="com.cice.crud.service.DatosPagoServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="datosPagoRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.DatosPagoRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="direcciones" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Direcciones" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="direccionesService" class="com.cice.crud.service.DireccionesServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="direccionesRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.DireccionesRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="imagenes" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Imagenes" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="imagenesService" class="com.cice.crud.service.ImagenesServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="imagenesRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.ImagenesRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="transacciones" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Transacciones" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="transaccionesService" class="com.cice.crud.service.TransaccionesServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="transaccionesRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.TransaccionesRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="usuario" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Usuario" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="usuarioService" class="com.cice.crud.service.UsuarioServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="usuarioRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.UsuarioRepositoryImpl"/> 

<bean id="datosUsuario" class="com.cice.crud.domain.DatosUsuario" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="datosUsuarioService" class="com.cice.crud.service.DatosUsuarioServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="datosUsuarioRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.DatosUsuarioRepositoryImpl"/>

<bean id="articulo" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Articulo" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="articuloService" class="com.cice.crud.service.ArticuloServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="articuloRepository" class="com.cice.crud.service.ArticuloRepositoryImpl"/>


<!-- JDBC connection properties are loaded to use in hibernate sessionfactory configuration -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory configuration. sessionFactory is used to create database connection by Hibernate.
This bean will be injected into HibernateDaoSupport, which is extended by our DB access layer UserRepositoryImpl.
sessionFactory will be automatically injected by spring as there is a setSessionFactory method in HibernateDaoSupport.
 -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.reeves.crud.domain.User</value>

            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.Articulo</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.CuentaBancaria</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.DatosPago</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.DatosUsuario</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.Direcciones</value>                
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.Imagenes</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.Paypal</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.Tarjeta</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.Transacciones</value>
            <value>com.cice.crud.domain.Usuario</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${jdbc.driverClassName}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Wrap database data manipulation methods with transactions -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Pero al acceder a una de las acciones, mapeadas en mi struts.xml, que usa el bean=datosPago me sale este error (os pongo la traza ). Sé que es por dependencia circular, lo que no consigo es averiguar cómo arreglarlo!

```
causa raíz

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datosPago' defined in file [C:\Users\Adela\Google Drive\workspaceEclipse2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NewUpStyle\WEB-INF\classes\applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'paypal' defined in file [C:\Users\Adela\Google Drive\workspaceEclipse2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NewUpStyle\WEB-INF\classes\applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datosPago': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:182)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:162)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:133)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:288)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:388)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:187)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

causa raíz

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'paypal' defined in file [C:\Users\Adela\Google Drive\workspaceEclipse2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NewUpStyle\WEB-INF\classes\applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datosPago': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:182)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:162)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:133)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:288)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:388)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:187)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

causa raíz

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datosPago': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:182)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:162)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:133)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:288)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:388)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:187)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Me podeis ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio adelagd, te invito a revisar [ask] para saber si hace falta acomodar algo de tu pregunta. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Bienvenida!

Comment: @adelagd Una consulta ya lo tienes agregado al persistence.xml

Comment: Spring no debe crear instancias del modelo, creo que ése es el problema

Comment: @RaulCacacho no tengo ningun persistence.xml.. creia que no hacia falta cuando se usan anotaciones. Si es asi.. me puedes decir alguna pagina para ver como se hace?

Comment: @PabloLozano no entiendo lo que me dices, lo siento..

Comment: @adelagd yo siempre he usado el persistence, este link te puede ayudar http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debe quitarse del applicationContext la entrada:

```
<bean id="datosPago" class="com.cice.crud.domain.DatosPago" scope="prototype"/>
```

También debe quitarse:

```
<bean id="direcciones" class="com.cice.crud.domain.Direcciones" scope="prototype"/>
```

Y en general cualquier otro tag  <**bean**> que en su atributo class tenga una clase del paquete:

**com.cice.crud.domain**

Esto por que como ha dicho Pablo Lozano Spring no debe crear instancias del modelo (las clases de ese paquete representan el modelo en el patrón MVC de tu aplicación).

Comment: exacto, era eso.. no entendia lo que me habia dicho Pablo.. muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda!